# GLPI and MantisBT on the same serveur, MantisBT error HTTP ERROR 403

Tags: debian, apache2, mantis, glpi

I have install glpi 10.0.11 and mantisbt 2.26.0 on the same server a linux debian 12 and i have the glpi web page but i have an error (HTTP ERROR 403) for the mantisbt.

When I disable glpi apache2 conf mantisBT is running.

Thank you for your help, if there is a solution to our problem.

I have 2 vhosts for glpi and mantisBT